# How to use AJAX request in TVML application?

Tags: ios, ajax, tvos, tvml

I have a working AJAX request in my browser. Now I need to use GET request for my JSON data in TVML project. How it is better to do it?

I was trying XMLHttpRequest, but it doesn't work or maybe I did something wrong?

```
function performRequest(type, route, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: type,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url + route,
            data: data
        });
    }

    function getChannels() {
        log(' > get channels');
        return performRequest('GET', 'channel/list', {
            id: browserId
        }).then(function (response) {
            response.data.forEach(function (channel) {
                channels[channel.id] = channel;
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to me to use jquery, not XMLHTTPRequest. Personally I did not succeed to run jquery with TVJS as it makes some suppositions about the Document class that TVJS does not satisfy. I did not analyze this issue in details, maybe you can find some workaround.

If you want to download a JSON resource with the native XMLHTTPRequest, try something like this:

```
/**
 * Downloads a JSON resource
 *
 * @param {Object}      options                 The options parameter.
 * @param {string}      options.resourcePath    Path to the JSON
 * @param {Function}    options.success         On success, will be called with the resulting JSON object
 * @param {Function}    [options.error]         Error callback
 */
getJSON(options) {

    var resourceXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    resourceXHR.responseType = "json";
    resourceXHR.addEventListener("load", (function () {
        options.success(resourceXHR.response);
    }));
    resourceXHR.addEventListener("error", (function () {
        options.error({status: resourceXHR.status, statusText: resourceXHR.statusText});
    }));
    resourceXHR.open("GET", options.resourcePath, true);
    resourceXHR.send();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [atvjs](https://emadalam.github.io/atvjs) framework for building TVML apps? It lets you build and quickly prototype apps without much noise, abstracting the underlying hassles and complexities of a conventional TVML app.

In [atvjs](https://emadalam.github.io/atvjs), ajax is implemented as a promise and you could do something like below:

```
ATV.Ajax.get('http://your_url')
        .then((response) => /* do something with response */)
        .catch((error) => /* handle errors */ );
```